# Visual Studio Code no me reconoce $ para Typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript, vscode, class

Consulta.. tengo el siguiente código en VSC

```
class Vehicle {
    brandName:string;

    constructor(b:string){
        this.brandName = b;
    }
    drive (){
        console.log('conduciendo un '${this.brandName}'');
    }
}
const vehicle = new Vehicle ('mazda');
vehicle.drive();
console.log(vehicle);
```

estoy teniendo un problemilla con VSC al querer usar la sintaxis de TypeScript
no me reconoce la sintaxis del this utilizado en el metodo de una clase;

deberia ser console.log('conduciendo un ${this.brandName}');

Y me tira como error que no tengo definiciones de jquery para utilizar $. Me da un comando ' i --save -dev @types/jquery ' , el cual coloco en la consola de Node y en la Terminal de VSC también, y descarga 2 packages, pero luego de reiniciar VSC sigue sin reconocerme la sintaxis como tal. Me dice que agregue el jquery en mi tsconfig. Pero, sinceramente, no sé si es en la consola/terminal, porque intenté con el comando tsconfig. pero no me lo reconoce en ningún lado; no sé si es un comando, o el nombre de una configuración que debo buscar en los ajustes del VSC.. Agradeceria ayuda

Comment: Como te comenta @BetaM debe ser `console.log(\`conduciendo un ${this.brandName}\`);`

Comment: Genial!! Me estaba ahogando en un vaso de agua. Mil gracias!

Answer (score 1):

El concepto que estás tratando implementar, al menos según lo que personalmente entendí de tu explicación, es [string template](https://www.codevscolor.com/typescript-template-string).

Ahora, la "particularidad" sintáctica de esta utilidad de lenguaje es el tipo de caracter necesario para instanciarla.

Normalmente, para declarar una cadena de texto usarías comillas simples o dobles (`'` o `"`). Sin embargo, para las plantillas de cadena de texto, has de usar la tilde invertida (`` ` ``), de la forma:

```js
drive (): void {
  console.log(`conduciendo un '${this.brandName}'`);
}
```

De manera que para la implementación:

```js
const vehicle = new Vehicle ('mazda');
vehicle.drive();
```

Generaría la salida `conduciendo un 'mazda'` en lugar de `conduciendo un '${this.brandName}'`